# Is it possible to @Observes in SessionScoped CDI bean a event generated by asynchronous stateless EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, cdi, ejb-3.1, weld

I need to recive an event after completing a long processing of user upload. I need to set return value to user session so I can displey it properly. I'm tring to do some CDI magic, as described here: http://piotrnowicki.com/2013/05/asynchronous-cdi-events/#toc-solution-3-ejb-producer-and-cdi-consumer (Async EJB Producer -> CDI Consumer).

**First attempt**

Caller & Reciver:

```
@SessionScoped
public class UploadController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @EJB
    private StatelessBeanLocal statelessBean;

    @Inject
    private SomeSessionCdi cdi;

    private Future<UploadedDTO> futureDto;

    public void observeUpload(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMPLETION) UploadFinishedEvent event) {
        logger.trace("Recived CDI event: %s", event);
        // FIXME: without @SessionScoped i'm reaching here, but futureDto == null
        cdi.setStateAfterUpload(dto);
    }

    public void upload(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, User user, UploadedFileInfo info) {
        logger.trace("Initiating an async upload processing of %s", info);
        futureDto = statelessBean.upload(baos, user);
        logger.trace("Initialized an async upload processing of %s", info);
    }

}
```

Processor:

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessBean implements StatelessBeanLocal {

    @Inject
    private transient Event<UploadFinishedEvent> eventTrigger;

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<UploadedDTO> upload(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, User user) {
        UploadedEntity entity = Unpacker.unpackBaos(baos);
        logger.trace("Uploaded file for: %s", entity);
        // [..] Long processing here
        // Invoking Thread.sleep(5000); to simulate a long process
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        UploadedDTO dto = null; // here a real value, of course
        logger.debug("Finished processing of upload for: %s", entity);
        eventTrigger.fire(new UploadFinishedEventImpl());
        logger.trace("After firing a CDI event for finished upload for: %s", entity);
        return new AsyncResult<>(dto);
    }

    // [..]
}
```

If CDI bean has a `@SessionScoped` annotation then I got: `SEVERE: WELD-000401 Failure while notifying an observer of event org.example.StatelessBean$UploadFinishedEventImpl@54c03555`

If CDI bean do not have a `@SessionScoped` annotation then I got `futureDto == null`

**Second attempt**

Changing EJB bean to changes logs but still not works:

Changed Stateless EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessBean implements StatelessBeanLocal {

    @Inject
    private transient Event<UploadFinishedEvent> eventTrigger;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sctx;

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<UploadedDTO> upload(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, User user) {
        UploadedEntity entity = Unpacker.unpackBaos(baos);
        logger.trace("Uploaded file for: %s", entity);
        // [..] Long processing here
        // Invoking Thread.sleep(5000); to simulate a long process
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        UploadedDTO dto = null; // here a real value, of course
        logger.debug("Finished processing of upload for: %s", entity);
        sctx.getBusinessObject(TemplateSetBeanLocal.class).fireUploadFinished();
        logger.trace("After firing a CDI event for finished upload for: %s", entity);
        return new AsyncResult<>(dto);
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void fireUploadFinished() {
        logger.debug("Before firing an UploadFinishedEvent: %s", sctx.getCallerPrincipal().toString());
        eventTrigger.fire(new UploadFinishedEventImpl());
        logger.debug("After firing an UploadFinishedEvent: %s", sctx.getCallerPrincipal().toString());
    }

    // [..]
}
```

Logs:

```
FINE: Finished processing of upload for: [sample-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip,application/zip,75,80KB,3cgvet]
FINEST: After firing a CDI event for finished upload for: [sample-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip,application/zip,75,80KB,3cgvet]
FINE: Before firing an UploadFinishedEvent: admin
FINE: After firing an UploadFinishedEvent: admin
SEVERE: No valid EE environment for injection of org.example.UploadController
FINEST: Recived CDI event: org.example.StatelessBean$UploadFinishedEventImpl@72514572
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
Without @SessionScoped, the bean is created again, and hence the futureDTO is null.
With @SessionScoped @AfterCompletion, you are processing after the transaction has committed. The weld error you got is probably due to some transactional behaviour. Although not in the example, you are probably invoking another EJB method to process uploadDTO in observeUpload(), causing a **committed** transaction (@AfterCompletion) to be suspended and resumed, which is not possible. The solution is to enter the observer method with a valid transaction, or don't do any transactional processing within that method. Sometimes an extra layer/method with the proper transactional-context will help.

Comment: Yes, I do a processing in `observeUpload()` but only in CDI. I actualize CDI session views. I do not call any bean in  whole stack that is part of `observerUpload()`.

Answer (score 0):

Mayby try something like this:

```
@SessionScoped
public class UploadController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @EJB
    private StatelessBeanLocal statelessBean;

    private Future<UploadedDTO> futureDto;

    public void uploadEnded(UploadedDTO dto) {
        logger.trace("Uploaded " + dto);
    }

    public void upload(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, User user, UploadedFileInfo info) {
        logger.trace("Initiating an async upload processing of %s", info);
        futureDto = statelessBean.upload(baos, user, this);
        logger.trace("Initialized an async upload processing of %s", info);
    }

}
```

EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessBean implements StatelessBeanLocal {

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<UploadedDTO> upload(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, User user, UploadController controller) {
        UploadedEntity entity = Unpacker.unpackBaos(baos);
        logger.trace("Uploaded file for: %s", entity);
        // [..] Long processing here
        // Invoking Thread.sleep(5000); to simulate a long process
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        UploadedDTO dto = null; // here a real value, of course
        logger.debug("Finished processing of upload for: %s", entity);
        controller.uploadEnded(dto);
        logger.trace("After firing a CDI event for finished upload for: %s", entity);
        return new AsyncResult(dto);
    }

    // [..]
}
```

Comment: Works only on `UploadController`. If `UploadController` has other `@Inject` fields, session is lost there.